# WHY Can't I Use SetTargetObjectId(UserId) and SetWhatId?

Tags: email, singleemailmessage

I have a very simple error handling case. I need to send an email to the running user, who almost certainly does not have an associated Contact record. I also need to specify the error record in question so I can send a link to it. Easy, right?

However, according to the documentation for [setWhatId](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setWhatId):

> If you specify a contact for the targetObjectId field, you can specify a whatId as well

So it doesn't work with a User Id. Why can't I send an email via template to a specific user about a specific record? This seems like a **huge** shortcoming in Apex. Creating a Contact record for each User is not an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Try specify the `targetObjectId` to be the user Id and in addition to that specify `mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);`

Comment: Yes I have also called `setSaveAsActivity(false)`. I didn't think it relevant to the post, but I am already doing that.

Comment: what if you remove any setCcAddresses or setBccAddresses ?

Comment: Also did you try with a VF email template with the recipient as a User ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was faced with this, I

1. Had a fixed Contact record with firstname = null, lastname = `ErrorNotificationsDoNotDelete`, email = `errornotifications@mycompany.com` under a known Account `MyCompany *do not delete*`
2. Used the the running User's email as the 'to:' address in the Apex outbound email message
3. Used the ID of the aforementioned Contact as the `targetObjectId` thereby enabling the `whatId` to be my object with the error details. The contact's Id was managed in a custom setting.

Answer (score 0):

One work-around is to use `Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate` to create your `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage`.  It allows a User for the `targetObjectId` and a `whatId`.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage m = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, UserInfo.getUserId(), myWhatId);
m.setSaveAsActivity(false);
```

Comment: This is great, but Salesforce email behavior is not consistent across UI and Apex. In apex we can use renderStoredEmailTemplate which does accept whoId as User/Contact/Lead. But when sending emails from the UI, it only supports Contact as p2_lkid parameter. It would be nice to have user/lead as recipient when sending emails from the UI too